# Rerender not working after states updated

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component `Rides` which sends data to child component via `props`.
Here is the `Child` component:

```
class LazyLoader extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loaderState: this.props.loaderState
    }
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    console.log(`inside componentWillReceiveProps ${nextProps.loaderState}`);
    if(this.props != nextProps) {
      this.setState({
        loaderState: nextProps.loaderState
      }, () => {console.log(`Finished setState for ${nextProps.loaderState}`)});
    }
  }

  render(){
    console.log(`loaderState: ${this.state.loaderState}`);
    return (
      this.state.loaderState ? (
        <View style={[styles.container]}>
          <ActivityIndicator style={styles.spinner} animating={true} size={60} color='#fff'/>
        </View>) : (<View/>)
    )
  }
}
```

And part of my parent component (here `Rides`) which send the updated data from its `state` to child's(here `LazyLoader`) `prop`:

```
export default class Rides extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleRidePress = this.handleRidePress.bind(this);
    this.navigateToRideDetails = this.navigateToRideDetails.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      flash: true
    };

  }

  handleRidePress(rideId){
    this.setState({
      flash: true
    }, () => {
      console.log(`Begining handleRidePress for rideId: ${rideId}`);
      if(doSomeTimeConsumingOperation){
        // Time consuming operation goes here
      }
      this.navigateToRideDetails({rideId: rideId, pingData:pingData.slice(), rideData: rideDetails});
    });
  }

  navigateToRideDetails(rideObj){

    this.setState({
      flash: false
    }, () => {console.log(`navigateToRideDetails setState cb`); this.props.navigation.navigate('RideLog', rideObj);});
  }

  render(){
    console.log(`flash: ${this.state.flash}`);
    return(
      <Gradient.FullGradient>
      <Reusables.LazyLoader loaderState={this.state.flash}/>
      <PRides rides={this.state.rideTiles} onDeletePress={this.deleteRide} navigation={this.props.navigation} onRideDetailPress={this.handleRidePress}/>
      </Gradient.FullGradient>
    )
  }
}
```

When `handleRidePress` function is called it updates the `flash` `state` using `setState()` but child component doesn't get rerender. I tried using `shouldComponentUpdate()` in both component and returned `true` by default, but It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified `navigateToRideDetails` to execute `setState` independently as react batches state updates that occur in event handlers and lifecycle methods. Thus, if we are updating state multiple times in a function handler, React will wait for event handling to finish before re-rendering. In my case, the `flash` value in `state` was getting reset after operation gets completed. Hence ActivityIndicator was not getting displayed.

Here is modified `navigateToRideDetails` function

```
navigateToRideDetails(rideObj){
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        flash: false
      }, ()=>{
        this.props.navigation.navigate('RideLog', rideObj);
      });
    }, 0); 
  }
```

This solves the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

I think error is in the way you are comparing two objects here:

```
if(this.props != nextProps) {
    ....
}
```

This is not the correct way to check whether two objects are same or not, check the values:

```
if(this.props.loaderState != nextProps.loaderState) {
    ....
}
```

Check this answer [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

Check this snippet:

```js
let a = {b: true};

let b = {b: true};

console.log(a == b);    //false
```

Comment: Ohh Thanks for pointing out that, but It doesn't solve the issue :(. I am getting log inside this condition `this.props.loaderState != nextProps.loaderState`, that means It's calling setState.

Comment: @SureshPrajapati sorry didn't get you, if it is calling setState then it will update the ui also, what's the issue now?

Comment: Rerender not working after states changed updated. That means It should show `ActivityIndicator`.`loaderState` value is true still I can't see ActivityIndicator.

Comment: `console.log('loaderState:', this.state.loaderState);` inside render of child is printing the updated value?

Comment: Yes, Exactly. 
Does changing `state` value twice is causing this problem? I set & reset the `flash` flag in one single operation

Comment: ooh yes, that will be the problem the transition is going very fast that is not observable in ui, use timeout first time update the state then update again after some time say 4-5 sec it will work.

Comment: Not exactly very fast UI change, because React batches state updates that occur in event handlers and lifecycle methods. Thus, if we update state multiple times, React will wait for event handling to finish before re-rendering.